# What is the maximum SPI speed for a slave Uno/clone?

Tags: arduino-uno, spi, speed

I have a Rapsberry Pi master sending SPI requests to an Uno Chinese clone slave : I send 16 characters to the Arduino, which answers 16 others characters. What I send is not important, it's the Arduino answer that matters.

When I set the speed on the Raspberry Pi at 1 Mbit/s with my C program, the received answer coming from the Arduino is mostly garbage (random characters), but this issue disappears with lower speeds.

So that leads me to this question : what is the maximum SPI speed for a slave Uno/clone, in order to have no errors ?

**Edit** : the Arduino code :

```
#include <SPI.h>

char receivingBuffer[5];
char sendingBuffer[5] = {'T', 'e', 's', 't', '!'};

volatile char bytes_received = 0;

void setup()
{

  SPCR |= bit(SPE);

  pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);

  SPI.attachInterrupt();

  SPDR = sendingBuffer[bytes_received];

}

ISR(SPI_STC_vect)
{

  if (++bytes_received == 5)
  {

    bytes_received = 0;

  }

  SPDR = sendingBuffer[bytes_received];

}

void loop()
{

  //

}
```

Also, the C code on the RPi :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wiringPiSPI.h>

#define SPI_CHANNEL 0
#define SPI_SPEED   1000000 // Hz.

int main(void)
{

   wiringPiSPISetup(SPI_CHANNEL, SPI_SPEED);

   while (1)
   {

      char buf[5] = {'T', 'e', 's', 't', '?'};

      printf("Sending   : %s\n", buf);

      wiringPiSPIDataRW(SPI_CHANNEL, buf, 5);

      printf("Receiving : %s\n\n", buf);

      sleep(1);

   }

   return 1;

}
```

Comment: The theoretical maximum is 8Mbps, which is F_CPU/2. What matters though is that you react fast enough to the requests for each byte and fill the buffer fast enough. That's down to your program to determine.

Comment: Please show your code. What you are doing in order to answer is highly relevant. If you are sending at 1 Mbits/s then the slave doesn't have many clock cycles to formulate a response.

Comment: I added the Arduino code.

Comment: What happens if you set a transfer speed of >1Mbps and put a delay in between each byte (at the Pi side) - does it start working then?

Comment: With 1.5 or 2 Mbps, I receive the first character of the expected answer, and the other characters are the sent message's ones.

Comment: I have a 1 second delay in the _while()_ loop between two messages, but I'm using the WiringPi library to work with SPI, and I don't think I can put a delay between two bytes.

Comment: Sure you can. Just send one byte instead of 5.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum speed for Arduino as a slave is F_CPU/4, so it's 4Mbps.
When the Arduino is the master it can work at F_CPU/2, so it's 8Mbps

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Do you have any source to confirm this ?

Comment: You can find this in ATmega328 datasheet. The ATmega328 is the chip on Arduino Uno.